# How does javac process Unicode glyphs?

Tags: java, unicode, javac

I tried `System.out.println("ñ");` and it prints `ñ`. Why didn't javac run through an error?

Comment: @JigarJoshi I thought javac would stick to characters similar to ASCII for easier processing.

Comment: @b16db0: No, javac can handle a lot of character sets, and by default it uses the platform default encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javac can be configured to have a source file encoding. That way, you can use character literals (and symbol names!) with non-ASCII characters.

If that matches what the file encoding actually is, all works well.

If not, you may get an error, but more likely, just some broken strings.

In order to print the text back again, the program needs to know which encoding to use when printing as well. All this needs to be configured correctly (the defaults in Java are not portable), otherwise you can get all kinds of broken text output.

Comment: Whoa, symbol names like something similar to `small letter n with tilde`?

Comment: Sure. `String ñ = "ñ"`. I would advise against it, though, definitely for class names (those need to go into the filesystem, that could break easily).

Comment: Both answers are useful. The check mark goes to you Sir for being very accommodating.

Answer (score 1):

Java `char` *and* `String` are natively in UTF-16. It can handle 'ñ' and "ñ".

[JLS-3.1. Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1) says (in part),

> The Java programming language represents text in sequences of 16-bit code units, using the UTF-16 encoding.

That is expanded on by [JLS-3.2. Lexical Structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2) which explains,

> A raw Unicode character stream is translated into a sequence of tokens, using the following three lexical translation steps, which are applied in turn:
>
> 1. A translation of Unicode escapes ([§3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3)) in the raw stream of Unicode characters to the corresponding Unicode character. A Unicode escape of the form \uxxxx, where xxxx is a hexadecimal value, represents the UTF-16 code unit whose encoding is xxxx. This translation step allows any program to be expressed using only ASCII characters.
> 2. A translation of the Unicode stream resulting from step 1 into a stream of input characters and line terminators ([§3.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.4)).
> 3. A translation of the stream of input characters and line terminators resulting from step 2 into a sequence of input elements ([§3.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.5)) which, after white space ([§3.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.6)) and comments ([§3.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.7)) are discarded, comprise the tokens ([§3.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.5)) that are the terminal symbols of the syntactic grammar ([§2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.3)).

Comment: True. But that does not explain how the compiler handles it. The source file is most likely not in UTF-16.

Comment: @Thilo Added JLS-3.2 which explains the lexical structure.